# Subset of Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>

Tags: c++, subset, sparse-matrix, eigen

Given,

```
SparseMatrix<double> A;
VectorXi r, c;
```

Is there an efficient way to extract the sparse matrix B using the vectors r and c? i.e.,

```
SparseMatrix<double> B = A(r,c);
```

The code provided here http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html#title1 doesnt seem to apply for sparse matrices?

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the code provided in the link for your specific problem?